# Using multiple visitors with BGL's BFS algorithm

Tags: boost, graph, breadth-first-search, boost-graph

I'm [trying](http://ideone.com/JTnipS) to use two visitors with BGL's BFS algorithm:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge = Graph::edge_descriptor;

namespace boost 
{
    template <typename event_type>
    class test_visitor: public default_bfs_visitor 
    {
        public:
            using event_filter = event_type;
            void discover_vertex(Vertex, const Graph&) const 
            {
                std::cout << "vertex discovered" << std::endl;
            }
    };
}

int main() 
{

    // Initialize a test graph
    Graph graph;
    Vertex vertexFoo = boost::add_vertex(graph);
    Vertex vertexBar = boost::add_vertex(graph);
    Vertex vertexBaz = boost::add_vertex(graph);
    boost::add_edge(vertexFoo, vertexBar, graph);
    boost::add_edge(vertexBar, vertexBaz, graph);

    // Initialize parents map
    std::vector<Vertex> parents_map(boost::num_vertices(graph));
    parents_map[vertexFoo] = vertexFoo;

    // Perform BFS with two listeners
    boost::breadth_first_search(
        graph,
        vertexFoo,
        boost::visitor(
            boost::make_bfs_visitor(
                std::make_pair(
                    boost::record_predecessors(&parents_map[0], boost::on_tree_edge()),
                    boost::test_visitor<boost::on_discover_vertex()>()
                )
            )
        )
    );

    return 0;
}
```

My custom visitor's listener (`discover_vertex`) is not invoked for some reason. I believe that the issue is related to how I pass listeners to the `breadth_first_search`. I was not able to find good docs about `boost::visitor` and `boost::make_bfs_visitor`.

B.t.w. my custom visitor works fine if I remove `using event_filter = event_type;` from it and pass it wrapped into just `boost::visitor` without `boost::make_bfs_visitor` which requires this `typedef`.

I also was not able to find any docs about `event_filter` and how to use multiple events (e.g. `on_discover_vertex` and `on_examine_edge`) simultaneously in one visitor. Do I get it right that `event_filter` specifies which events the visitor will process? Links to docs about this are appreciated.

Comment: Docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/EventVisitor.html. You can simply combine more methods by overriding more than one, don't use `make_bfs_visitor` in such a case (because it assumes `EventVisitor`s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, no need to declare the visitor in the boost namespace. This is a bad idea, don't inject your own stuff into namespaces you don't control.

Next if you use `make_bfs_visitor` to piece together visitors for specific `event_filter`s, you need to implement `operator()` not `discover_vertex`:

```
template <typename event_type>
struct test_visitor: public default_bfs_visitor 
{
    using event_filter = event_type;

    void operator()(Vertex, Graph const&) const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Lastly, the `event_type` argument was simply wrong, drop the parentheses:

```
test_visitor<boost::on_discover_vertex>()
```

#### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22047c995f7c426e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/visitors.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge   = Graph::edge_descriptor;

template <typename event_type>
struct test_visitor: public boost::default_bfs_visitor {
    using event_filter = event_type;

    void operator()(Vertex, Graph const&) const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Initialize a test graph
    enum { Foo, Bar, Baz, NUMVERTICES };
    Graph graph(NUMVERTICES);
    boost::add_edge(Foo, Bar, graph);
    boost::add_edge(Bar, Baz, graph);

    // Initialize parents map
    std::vector<Vertex> parents_map(boost::num_vertices(graph));
    parents_map[Foo] = Foo;

    // Perform BFS with two listeners
    boost::breadth_first_search(graph, Foo,
        boost::visitor(
            boost::make_bfs_visitor(
                std::make_pair(
                    boost::record_predecessors(&parents_map[0], boost::on_tree_edge()),
                    test_visitor<boost::on_discover_vertex>()
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```